# How to do a relative import from the parent directory?

Tags: python, relative-import

I have searched this and found many answers, all of which tell me to do exactly what I am doing, here is my directory structure:

```
app/
+-- __init__.py
+-- app_manager.py
+-- app_gui/
|   +-- __init__.py
|   +-- app_gui.py
```

in app_gui.py I have:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from app_manager import AppManager
```

in app manager:

```
class AppManager():
    def __init__(self):
    """ default constructor for app manager """
```

In Visual Code, it actually resolves this to an auto completion, which tells me that at least Visual Code sees it as correctly done. However, if I run this I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named "app_manager"
```

**Edit**

Full stack trace when changing to `from app.app_manager import AppManager`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File ".\app_gui\app_gui.py", line 4, in <module>
     from app_manager import AppManager
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app_manager'
```

Comment: where is your `__main__` here?

Comment: @Mark I've tried putting it in app_gui and in app_manager, both give me the same error, child packages cant import anything (even if they are in the same directory)

Comment: In your searching did you ever read [**Relative imports for the billionth time**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running python code like this is hacky at best.

Use a [setup.py](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html)
This will require some small changes but will pay immediate benefits.
You will then be able to use your `app` package like any other installed package.

### New Directory Structure

```
.
├── app
│   ├── app_gui
│   │   ├── app_gui.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── app_manager.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── setup.py
```

### setup.py

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(name='app',
      version='0.0.1-dev',
      description='My app package',
      install_requires=['tkinter'],
      packages=find_packages(),
      zip_safe=False)
```

### app_gui.py

```
from app.app_manager import AppManager

manager = AppManager()
```

## Putting it all together

From the same dir as `setup.py` run:
  `$> python setup.py develop`

This will symlink the package into your site-pacakges folder where you can treat it like any other package. i.e. import it using `import app` from scripts located anywhere on your system.

Comment: Okay thank you, so where should the __main__ go in this scenario?

Comment: @Aserian it depends on how you intend to use the package. Typically I'd have a seperate `main.py` which imports the package and uses it in a `__main__`.  This function might do something like `import app app.run()`

Answer (score 2):

Since `app_manager.py` is a directory above `app_gui.py`, I believe your import (if you wish to use a relative import) should be

```
from ..app_manager import AppManager
```

EDIT to address error in comments: If you try to run this file directly, you will get a `ValueError` like in the comments. Relative imports work between modules inside of packages. Let's say that you use the import I wrote above, and then you have a file ONE LEVEL ABOVE your `app` directory called `stuff.py`, with the following contents:

```
import app.app_gui.app_gui
print('hello')
```

Running `stuff.py` would look like:

```
$ python stuff.py 
hello
```

In other words, executing a file with relative imports directly with the python interpreter will result in an error, as it was not intended to be used this way. Rather, your model should be imported and executed by something outside of the module itself.

If you have a `__main__` file inside of your `app` directory with the exact same code, you can also execute the module directly.

```
$ cat app/__main__.py 
import app.app_gui.app_gui
print('hello')

$ python -m app
hello
```

Comment: "ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package"

Comment: python app_gui.py when the main was in app_gui.py, python app_manager.py when I tried switching it to app_manager.py

Comment: Answer edited to address this. Let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: Yes sorry, many edits but this should be good for you now, and potentially TMI lol.